# What is the time complexity \big(O) of this specific function?

Tags: c, loops, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

What is the time comlexity of this function(f1)?

as I can see that the first loop(i=0)-> (n/4 times) the second one(i=3)->(n/4 - 3 times).... etc, the result is: (n/3)*(n/4 + (n-3)/4 + (n-6)/4 + (n-9)/4 ....

And I stop here, how to continue?

```
int f1(int n){
  int s=0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i+=3)
    for (int j=n; j>i; j-=4)
      s+=j+i;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it O(n^2)? If n doubles, the execution time will quadruple. This is similar to comparing each array element `for (i=0;i<n;++i) for (j=0;j<i;++j)` so i guess it's O(n^2). The constants does not really matter for time complexity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing about Big(O) notation is that it eliminates 'constants'. The objective is to determine *trend* as input size grows without concern for specific numbers.

Think of it as determining the curve on a graph where you don't know the number ranges of the x and y axes.

So in your code, even though you skip most of the values in the range of `n` for each iteration of each loop, this is done at a constant rate. So regardless of how many you actually skip, this still scales relative to `n^2`.

It wouldn't matter if you calculated any of the following:

```
1/4 * n^2
0.0000001 * n^2
(1/4 * n)^2
(0.0000001 * n)^2
1000000 + n^2
n^2 + 10000000 * n
```

In Big O, these are all equivalent to `O(n^2)`. The point being that once `n` gets big *enough* (whatever that may be), all the lower order terms and constant factors become irrelevant in the 'big picture'.

(*It's worth emphasising that this is why on small inputs you should be wary of relying too heavily on Big O. That's when constant overheads can still have a big impact.*)

Comment: @sam0101 As others have said, a simple inspection of the loops reveal complexity to be fraction of N times fraction of N: `an * bn = abn^2 ==> O(n^2)`. But if you're looking for a formal proof, I assume this is for a homework exercise. If so, I suggest you check your notes for an example proof for Selection Sort. It will follow the same principal.

Comment: So if it n^2 - n^/4 ... it is still O(n^2)?

Comment: @sam0101 Yes `n^2 - (n^2)/4` can be written as `(1 - 1/4)* n^2` or `¾ n²` and 3/4 is simply a constant coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Key observation:** The inner loop executes `(n-i)/4` times in step `i`, hence`i/4` in step `n-i`.

Now sum all these quantities for `i = 3k, 3(k-1), 3(k-2), ..., 9, 6, 3, 0`, where `3k` is the largest multiple of `3` before `n` (i.e., `3k <= n < 3(k+1)`):

```
3k/4 + 3(k-1)/4 + ... + 6/4 + 3/4 + 0/4 = 3/4(k + (k-1) + ... + 2 + 1)
                                        = 3/4(k(k+1))/2
                                        = O(k^2)
                                        = O(n^2)
```

because `k <= n/3 <= k+1` and therefore `k^2 <= n^2/9 <= (k+1)^2 <= 4k^2`

Answer (score -1):

In theory it's "O(n*n)", but...

What if the compiler felt like optimising it into this:

```
int f1(int n){
  int s=0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i+=3)
    s += table[i];
  return s;
}
```

Or even this:

```
int f1(int n){
  if(n <= 0) return 0;
  return table[n];
}
```

Then it could also be "O(n)" or "O(1)".

Note that on the surface these kinds of optimisations seem impractical (due to worst case memory costs); but with a sufficiently advanced compiler (e.g. using "whole program optimisation" to examine all callers and determine that `n` is always within a certain range) it's not inconceivable. In a similar way it's not impossible for all of the callers to be using a constant (e.g. where a sufficiently advanced compiler can replace things like `x = f1(123);` with `x = constant_calculated_at_compile_time`).

In other words; in practice, the time complexity of the original function depends on how the function is used and how good/bad the compiler is.

Comment: Obviously selection-sort can at any time be replaced with merge/quick/heap/other-sort. That doesn't mean selection-sort becomes `O(n.log(n))`. NOTE: The complexity of the _actual code_ doesn't change because the compiler chooses to apply some particular optimisation. If the compiled code is optimised and transposed to do something different (but presumably equivalent), it's _different code_ that has different complexity. If the compiler were to call the function at compile-time to transpose the binary into const lookups, then the complexity `O(n^2)` _still takes place at compile-time_.

Comment: @Watcher: In theory you're right; but for both examples (yours and mine) we still reach the "in theory, theory is useful; in practice, theory is misleading hogwash that's worse than nothing" stage. Nobody cares what happens at compile time (for non-trivial source code compile time is "O(My God)" due to the expense of all kinds of optimisations - e.g. just figuring out the ideal way allocate registers is a known "NP-hard' problem) and "what happens at run-time in practice" is the only thing that actually matters.

Comment: I don't this as theory vs. practice. While you're correct that an optimiser could use a substitute algorithm (changing the performance of the program); it's fundamentally incorrect to claim this affects the complexity of the ***original function*** in any way. To wit, the following is wrong: "_in practice, the time complexity of the original function depends on how the function is used and how good/bad the compiler is_" (I'd guess that's why this was down-voted.)

Comment: Furthermore, I'd actually argue that although it's useful to have a broader understanding of complexity analysis: the OP is clearly seeking an understanding of how to evaluate a specific function. This doesn't answer that. Instead it seems to encourage laziness, as in: "It could be optimised so don't bother thinking about it." IMHO understanding theory and understanding practice go hand-in-hand. One cannot rely on the compiler solving all your problems. And in _practice_ you're going to want to understand how code that the compiler ***didn't change*** affects performance.